# How to make Django DateTimeField to store Pacific time with UTC format

Tags: django, timezone, utc

After reading many doc, I am confused by UTC, UTC timezone and how it's used in Django.

Is UTC format and UTC timezone same thing? Can UTC format store Pacific timezone date+time?

I have a django project with database and UI.

```
class FunModel(models.Model):
   fun_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

What I am expecting:

1) Page 1. click a button in a browser in Pacific timezone. Server to create/store (on server side, not client to create time) 'fun_time' as Pacific time zone date + time (not UTC zone, but format is UTC format)

2) Page 2. When page 2 is loaded. it retrieves time as Pacific date + time (Not UTC zone)

3) In database, I expect to see time stored is Pacific date+time.

4) As far as my understanding, FunModel class will store time as Pacific time with UTC format. The timezone is configured in settings.

```
----Settings.py

# Tried 'US/Pacific' as well. No difference. Date+time stored in db is the same. Really confused!
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'  

# Only for retrieving date from db to be Pacific by calling active(USER_TIME_ZONE)? 
USER_TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific'  

# With above 2 settings, date stored/retrieved will be Pacific zone automatically. Not really!

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

My expectation is database will store time as US/Pacific timezone, and the time format is UTC (always UTC format right?)

```
----Page1_Save.py
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.activate(settings.USER_TIME_ZONE)
time_param = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

fun_time_obj = FunModel(fun_time=time_param)
fun_time_obj.save()

# time_param = 2019-04-16 01:00:00
# database: 2019-04-16 01:00:00 + 7 hours = 2019-04-16 08:00:00  (Not correct!)
```

I am expecting database: 2019-04-16 01:00:00.

I also tried,

```
time_param = timezone.now()
```

Same result:

```
# time_param = 2019-04-16 01:00:00
# database: 2019-04-16 01:00:00 + 7 hours = 2019-04-16 08:00:00  (Not correct!)
```

Where I did wrong?

```
---Page2_Load.py  (Use Q to compare date stored in db)

# Browser in Pacific timezone without timezone passed to server. Just time picked from Javascript.
ui_date = '2019-04-16 01:00:00'
```

I want to use Q function to compare:

```
Q(fun_time__exact=ui_date)
```

A) If database time is Pacific time, comparison is valid.

B) If database time is UTC time, the comparison is not valid. Now, I can't compare the date stored in db!!! How to fix it?

C) I don't want date+time in database to be UTC timezone!!!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: mysql database.

Comment: UTC is not a format.  Any discussion of "UTC format" is nonsensical.  It's like saying you like chocolate cars.  You might like red cars and chocolate cake, but they are very different things.

Comment: *I don't want date+time in database to be UTC timezone!!!* Then you can't set `USE_TZ` to `True`. See the first sentence of the timezone documentation.

Comment: USE_TZ = False. timezone.activate(settings.USER_TIME_ZONE)
time_param = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) (To get Pacific time to store in db) will cause error: ValueError: localtime() cannot be applied to a naive datetime. timezone.now() will get UTC timezone time (7 hour ahead of Pacific). How to get Pacific time and store Pacific time in db?

Comment: Tried USE_TZ = False, time_param = datetime.datetime.now(). No crash, but it's 7 hours ahead and is not Pacific time.

Comment: I just realized cloud server is UTC timezone.  USE_TZ = False, time_param = datetime.datetime.now() is UTC time, which is correct. Then, how to make db to store Pacific time, and how to create current time to be Pacific automatically, without performing converting it every place current time is retrieved?

Comment: TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific', USER_TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific'. time_param = datetime.datetime.now() is still UTC time, not Pacific time.

Comment: On server,  from time import gmtime, strftime
      print(strftime("%Z", gmtime())) output is: UTC. On client, output is: PST

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, but I am more confused by Django time zone settings.

Server computer system clock is UTC timezone.

---settings.py

```
# Totally useless
#TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'  # comment out, and server runs well.

# I suspect this is useless as well. 
USER_TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific'  

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = False   # Make server timezone not aware.
```

---page1_save.py

```
  from datetime import datetime
  import  pytz
  utc = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())  # Generate time from server, which is UTC timezone
  instance_time_zone = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')  
  time_param = utc.astimezone(instance_time_zone)
  time_param = time_param.replace(tzinfo=None)  # USE_TZ = False. Make it without timezone.

  fun_time_obj = FunModel(fun_time=time_param)
  fun_time_obj.save()
```

Now, time in db is Pacific time, which is what I expect.

TIME_ZONE, USER_TIME_ZONE are useless in this case, when USE_TZ = False. Also, with USE_TZ = True, TIME_ZONE = 'What ever' seems also useless, as I tried TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific', USER_TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific', and can't get db to store pacific time.